React Native - iOS. failed to build ios project, "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65. to debug build logs further when run app
I am trying to run my already running android react-native project in mac device.
first time I flow :
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
npx react-native run-android
It gives me the above error, when I recreate a new project with same name, and use the same packages.json with same RN version 0.76.0 and iOS version is 15.1, it doesn't work
the project name has no space or special characters, it only contains alphabets upper-case and lower-case
the package I use =>
{
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.0.0",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.9.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "6.7.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
"axios": "^1.7.7",
"i18next": "^23.16.4",
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-i18next": "^15.1.0",
"react-native": "^0.76.1",
"react-native-animated-pagination-dot": "^0.4.0",
"react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.11",
"react-native-device-info": "^14.0.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.20.2",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
"react-native-localization": "^2.3.2",
"react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.12",
"react-native-pdf": "^6.7.5",
"react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.7",
"react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.1",
"react-native-root-siblings": "^5.0.1",
"react-native-root-toast": "^3.6.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.12.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.35.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
"react-redux": "^8.0.5",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
}
